# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when accessing Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have following function which returns me list of current sheets

```
Function getListOfSheetsW() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim sheetNames() As Variant

  ReDim sheetNames(1 To Sheets.Count)
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    sheetNames(i) = Sheets(i).name
  Next i

  getListOfSheetsW = sheetNames
End Function
```

This function returns array starting at position 1. My goal was to create same function but starting with position 0, I've tried:

```
Function getListOfSheetsNW() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim sheetNames() As Variant

  ReDim sheetNames(Sheets.Count - 1)
  For i = 0 To Sheets.Count
    sheetNames(i) = Sheets(i + 1).name
  Next i

  getListOfSheetsNW = sheetNames
End Function
```

But this return me:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

What is wrong with my code?

PS: I'm calling those functions following way:

```
Sub callGetListOfSheetsW()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ' arr = getListOfSheetsW()
    arr = getListOfSheetsNW()

    MsgBox arr(1)
    MsgBox arr(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 0 To Sheets.Count - 1` as `0` counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worksheet count will always be one based.

```
Function getListOfSheetsNW() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim sheetNames() As Variant

  ReDim sheetNames(Sheets.Count - 1)
  For i = 0 To Sheets.Count - 1    '<~~This. Alternately as For i = 0 To UBound(sheetNames)
    sheetNames(i) = Sheets(i + 1).name
  Next i

  getListOfSheetsNW = sheetNames
End Function
```

Comment: Oh, this was scholar mistake. Thank you